# In app purchase can we refund the In App purchase

Tags: iphone, storekit

Is there a programatical way in which an In App purchase is refunded back to the user?

I have an application with a certain buyable feature. The user buys it but somehow doesnt like it. Is there any programatical way in which I can make the user get back his spent money?

Comment: +1 for the good question about a nicely user-centric requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. This is the same as with buying an app from the AppStore - you cannot say that you did not like the app, return it and get your money back. This is one of the reason why there are free lite versions of some apps. This allows users to check the app for free before they buy it. Maybe you could use the same mechanism in your app? Give some content for free and if the users see that it is what the need they could buy more of it.

Comment: Though both are correct, i found this answer more apt to the requirement that i have

Comment: Refund for the apps *are* possible. http://www.labnol.org/software/itunes-app-store-refunds/13838/

Answer (score 2):

No. The user will need to contact Apple Customer Services who will then decide whether or not to issue a refund. The refund will be taken from your apps earnings, I believe.

Comment: Actually, Apple's support page at http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1933 says `For issues with an in app purchase, you will need to contact the developer. The developer's contact information can be found on the application's information page from the App Store.`

Comment: @chrispix but that says nothing about refunds. Apple states that all sales are final. Of course there is nothing stopping you from just giving the money back to the customer using something like paypal or a direct transfer, but that isn't what the question was asking.